# Use VBA to pull store locations

Tags: vba, dictionary

I am trying to pull all the store locations from several different websites, for example Sephora http://www.sephora.com/store-locations-events and Freshpet http://freshpet.com/storelocator/.

Every site constrains the radius for the search, so to find all locations, the only thing I have come up with is cycling through every zip code and then filtering out duplicates. Is there a way to use VBA to manipulate the search radius using VBA to just search the entire United States, instead of only up to 100 miles? That way, I could just do one search for each of these sites.

Thanks!

Comment: Any code? What have you tried? You need to show some effort, so that we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it on those javascript sites.  VBA works great with HTML, but not so great with javascript and flash.  Also, the code isn't even exposed, so the search results must be generated dynamically from the server.  I just did a search on that freshpet site and got the results then did a right-click and viewed the source code and nothing that I searched for was in the code.